# highlight all duplicates rows in excel

Tags: excel

i put all the value from A,B,E,F,G,I columns to a new columns Q. Can i use this formula on this column? =MIN(LINE(Q5)*(IF(Q7=Q6;1;0))) its not working NOTE* My data start from row 5 –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the function 'line' does? Within MIN function, you need to pass a list of values; if Line returns a value and the IF statement returns another, there must be a comma between them.

```
=MIN(LINE(Q5),(IF(Q7=Q6;1;0)))
```

**Edit:**

[HERE](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Duplicates.html) there's a good example of how to highlight duplicated entries. Basically, it will:

- Concatenate the whole line into one single cell (I believe you'll have A1+B1+D1+E1+F1+G1)
- Use a CountIf function to check which ones are duplicated
- Apply a special format into the rows where the CountIf returns > 1.

Hope this helps!

Rgds

Comment: is there any other way to do this. i am just trying to find duplicate rows and highlight them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you asked the question twice : [excel 2007 duplicate row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312571/excel-2007-duplicate-row/5313113#5313113) ?

Btw, Tiago solution is simplier (so better) than mine for just highlighting row. My solution can return the line where the duplicate exists...

For highlighting and using COnditional Formatting, the countif is better and could be used directly in the Conditional Formating formula (no need to create another column).

Regards,